# Fill area between two segments in a 3D plot {rgl}

Tags: r, 3d, polygon, rgl

I have made a tetrahedron using vertex coordinates and line segments using the function plot3d() from the package {rgl}. The code below makes the [mentioned plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cH1C.jpg)

```
library("rgl")
CCl4=c(5,5,5,10)
Luminol=c(0.01,0.001,0.005,0.005)
Na2CO3=c(0.01,0.01,0.1,0.05)

plot3d( Luminol, Na2CO3, CCl4, type = "s")

for(i in 1:4){
    for(k in 1:4){
                 segments3d(x=Luminol[c(i,k)],y=Na2CO3[c(i,k)],z=CCl4[c(i,k)])
                 }
        }
```

Now, I want to fill the area between the points (preferably using a RGB color so I can define transparency using an alpha value) but I have not found a polygon() like function in rgl. Is there a way to fill this area?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could also use `polygon3d()` if you really need a general polygon rather than just triangles as Mike describes.  Not sure why you couldn't find it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? Wasn't completely clear on the request. I added color to everything to help figure it out.

```
library("rgl")
CCl4=c(5,5,5,10)
Luminol=c(0.01,0.001,0.005,0.005)
Na2CO3=c(0.01,0.01,0.1,0.05)

clrs <- c("red","blue","green","darkgrey")

plot3d( Luminol, Na2CO3, CCl4, type = "s",col=clrs)

for(i in 1:4){
  clr <- clrs[i]
  for(k in (i+1):4){
      v <- c(i,k)
      segments3d(Luminol[v],Na2CO3[v],CCl4[v],color=clr)
  }
}

for (i in 1:4){
  clr <- clrs[i]
  v <- setdiff(1:4,i)
  triangles3d(Luminol[v],Na2CO3[v],CCl4[v],alpha=0.5,col=clr)
}
```

yielding:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what we was needing. The colors that you added was a nice touch and really helps. Sorry for the unclearness. Thank you for the answer.